# Issues with ARP poisoning using ettercap

Tags: networking, security

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask.

I am currently attempting to use a program called Ettercap to initiate a man in the middle attack (within my own network, in case I need to specify.). In this case I am attempted to use this program to initiate an ARP poisoning attack between my laptop and my router

I enter the IP addresses of the two devices into ettercap and begin the attack. I then open wireshark to attempt to monitor the traffic. In wireshark I am able to see the traffic intended for the laptop, however it just consists of TCP re transmission attempts that always fail. And from the laptop I am unable to access the internet.

This leads me to believe that there is almost certainly some kind of issue where my device is not properly forwarding packets between the router and laptop. I have made sure to execute: "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" to enable forwarding.

At this point I have no idea where to go from here. Any help or further reading would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The question you have posted is a non-Ubuntu flavor question, which means the question does not come under this community. Kindly share your question in other Stack like Stack Overflow.